# Nokogiri not working in block : uninitialized constant ::Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I successfully installed Ruby 1.9.1 and Nokogiri, however, when I try to use Nokogiri I get the following error:

```
uninitialized constant ::Nokogiri
```

This seems to happen because the Nokogiri gem cannot be found. This is my code:

```
File::open("test.html"){|file|
  puts file.class  => file 
  page = Nikogiri::HTML(file) => uninitialized constant ::Nokogiri
  puts page.class  
}
```

But this works:

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("test.html"))
file = open("test.html")  => file
page = Nokogiri::HTML(file) 
puts page.class  => document
```

So could you help me find out what is wrong?

Answer (score 6):

The code has a typo:

```
page = Nikogiri::HTML(file) # => uninitialized constant ::Nokogiri
#       ^
```